# Kubernetes Ingress to Pod pathing question (Nginx Ingress)

Tags: kubernetes, url-rewriting, nginx-ingress

I'm fairly new to Kubernetes, and I'm trying to figure out how to get multiple pods of the same container image running at different paths in my cluster. I've pasted my k8s manifests below. In this scenario, my app (website) is listening on the root path. However, when the Ingress matches it and forwards it to my Pod, it's requesting the `/app` path, which returns a 404, because, again, my app is listening at root (`/`). I can make the app listen to `/app`, however it requires a rebuild of that image and restricts my ability to run the ***same exact image*** at various paths within my cluster. For example, I'd love to run the **same** website at `/app2` without rebuilding a special image just for that path.

I feel like the answer has something to do with [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), but I've tried various permutations of it and I can't figure it out. I feel like it's something simple I'm missing.

This is my deployment manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: application
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: application
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: application
          image: foo-app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: "http"
```

Here is my service manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: application-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: application
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

and finally, here is my ingress resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: some-random.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: application-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /app
```

Comment: Is the app you are trying to serve at a different path, a web application? If the answer is yes, it may not be a good idea to serve it at a different path from the expected one, depending on how the web pages are built. What I mean is that, if the index.html for example references css or js files with absolute paths, it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /app/$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: application-service-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: some-random.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-1
          servicePort: 80
```